# Why angularjs router is not working here?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, url, ionic-framework

I've installed ionic by this way:

```
npm install ionic
ionic start hello blank
cd hello
ionic platform add android
ionic build android
ionic serve
```

It works perfect.

Then I tried to try to compile this code: http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/odqCz

I've just copied and pasted the html in index.html and the js in app.js, and I've added the script tag in the html. But I get the following error in my console, and the page is not displayed:

```
GET http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.12/js/performance-now.map 404 (Not Found) (index):158
GET http://192.168.1.136:8100/contact.html 404 (Not Found) ionic.bundle.js:15978
GET http://192.168.1.136:8100/nav-stack.html 404 (Not Found) ionic.bundle.js:15978
GET http://192.168.1.136:8100/about.html 404 (Not Found) ionic.bundle.js:15978
GET http://192.168.1.136:8100/facts2.html 404 (Not Found) ionic.bundle.js:15978
GET http://192.168.1.136:8100/facts.html 404 (Not Found) ionic.bundle.js:15978
GET http://192.168.1.136:8100/sign-in.html 404 (Not Found) ionic.bundle.js:15978
GET http://192.168.1.136:8100/home.html 404 (Not Found) ionic.bundle.js:15978
GET http://192.168.1.136:8100/tabs.html 404 (Not Found) ionic.bundle.js:15978
GET http://192.168.1.136:8100/forgot-password.html 404 (Not Found) ionic.bundle.js:15978
GET http://192.168.1.136:8100/sign-in.html 404 (Not Found) ionic.bundle.js:15978
```

What is going on here? Why in my codepen is working and my localhost doesn't interpret properly the fake-urls of angularjs?

Comment: did you add all the templates as well, as it is saying 404 for the script templates over here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you have not included the script templates in the index.html otherwise a 404 cannot appear in the console.

script tags which might got missed:

```
 <script id="templates/tabs.html" type="text/ng-template">
   <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-positive">

    <ion-tab title="Home" icon="ion-home" href="#/tab/home">
      <ion-nav-view name="home-tab"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

    <ion-tab title="About" icon="ion-ios7-information" href="#/tab/about">
      <ion-nav-view name="about-tab"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

    <ion-tab title="Contact" icon="ion-ios7-world" ui-sref="tabs.contact">
      <ion-nav-view name="contact-tab"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

  </ion-tabs>
</script>

<script id="templates/home.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-view title="Home">
    <ion-content class="padding">
      <p>Example of Ionic tabs. Navigate to each tab, and
      navigate to child views of each tab and notice how
      each tab has its own navigation history.</p>
      <p>
        <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/facts">Scientific Facts</a>
      </p>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>

<script id="templates/facts.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-view title="Facts">
    <ion-content class="padding">
      <p>Banging your head against a wall uses 150 calories an hour.</p>
      <p>Dogs have four toes on their hind feet, and five on their front feet.</p>
      <p>The ant can lift 50 times its own weight, can pull 30 times its own weight and always falls over on its right side when intoxicated.</p>
      <p>A cockroach will live nine days without it's head, before it starves to death.</p>
      <p>Polar bears are left handed.</p>
      <p>
        <a class="button icon ion-home" href="#/tab/home"> Home</a>
        <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/facts2">More Facts</a>
      </p>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>

<script id="templates/facts2.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-view title="Also Factual">
    <ion-content class="padding">
      <p>111,111,111 x 111,111,111 = 12,345,678,987,654,321</p>
      <p>1 in every 4 Americans has appeared on T.V.</p>
      <p>11% of the world is left-handed.</p>
      <p>1 in 8 Americans has worked at a McDonalds restaurant.</p>
      <p>$283,200 is the absolute highest amount of money you can win on Jeopardy.</p>
      <p>101 Dalmatians, Peter Pan, Lady and the Tramp, and Mulan are the only Disney cartoons where both parents are present and don't die throughout the movie.</p>
      <p>
        <a class="button icon ion-home" href="#/tab/home"> Home</a>
        <a class="button icon ion-chevron-left" href="#/tab/facts"> Scientific Facts</a>
      </p>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>

<script id="templates/about.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-view title="About">
    <ion-content class="padding">
      <h3>Create hybrid mobile apps with the web technologies you love.</h3>
      <p>Free and open source, Ionic offers a library of mobile-optimized HTML, CSS and JS components for building highly interactive apps.</p>
      <p>Built with Sass and optimized for AngularJS.</p>
      <p>
        <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/navstack">Tabs Nav Stack</a>
      </p>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>

<script id="templates/nav-stack.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-view title="Tab Nav Stack">
    <ion-content class="padding">
      <p><img src="http://ionicframework.com/img/diagrams/tabs-nav-stack.png" style="width:100%"></p>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>

<script id="templates/contact.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-view title="Contact">
    <ion-content>
      <div class="list">
        <div class="item">
          @IonicFramework
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          @DriftyTeam
        </div>
      </div>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>
```

[Working Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/DBEBghvi5humxoE3yjSt?p=preview)

Comment: Yes, I had been added it. I pasted your code and now works. Magic.